# JMeter: How to run the https request by providing client certificates

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, jmeter

I would like to test the https request by providing client certifacates. I have certificates of type .pem. how should I pass the certificates to the request?

Answer (score 0):

This blog article will give you all the details :

- https://flood.io/blog/mutual-two-way-ssl-with-jmeter/

Also read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration

Comment: The first link is broken. In the second link I couldn't find how to use a *.PEM file.

Comment: I could just fix the link. Unfortunately it seems the PEM file needs to be converted into an Java Keystore.